# Add multiple copies of row to matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Is there an elegant way to **add multiple copies of the same row to a matrix** ? Below is an example that solves the problem. However, this example is slow and not elegant coding.

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),ncol=3)
m0 <- m

r <- c(10,20,30)

#Correct example
for (i in c(1,2))
  m[i,] <- r

print(m)

#    [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   10   20   30
#[2,]   10   20   30
#[3,]    3    6    9


#Attempts below look straightforward but lead to incorrect results
m <- m0

m[1:2,] <- apply(m[1:2,],1,function(x)r)
print(m)

#  [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   10   30   20
#[2,]   20   10   30
#[3,]    3    6    9

m <- m0
m[1:2,] <- r
print(m)

#  [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   10   30   20
#[2,]   20   10   30
#[3,]    3    6    9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could construct a second matrix from the vector `r` and insert it into `m` as follows:

```
m[1:2, ] <- matrix(r, ncol = 3, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
m
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   10   20   30
#[2,]   10   20   30
#[3,]    3    6    9
```

---

Another option is to `t`ranspose `m`, insert `r` and `t`ranspose again:

```
m <- t(m)
m[, 1:2] <- r
m <- t(m)
m
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   10   20   30
#[2,]   10   20   30
#[3,]    3    6    9
```

I haven't benchmarked the performance, though.

Comment: @docendo-dicimus Thank you for the quick answer. Your example is easier to read and understand.  Speed measurements (10000 repetitions of matrix operation in both examples) result in 43 ms for my example and 74 ms for yours.

Comment: @docendo-dicimus  Second solution has worse performance (187 ms for 10000 repetitions), most likely because the whole matrix is modified multiple times.

Comment: Not much experience of R, but to avoid a loop you can use the apply function like this: `rows <- 1:2; m[rows,] <-  sapply(rows,function(x) { m[x,] <-  r })`

Answer (score 0):

As to my knowledge, the **for-loop is** the **fastest** way to solve the problem. A faster solution would be to **select a different data structure in R, where the records are in the columns** instead of in the rows.

Below are speed measurements for the solutions by @docendo-discimus and me and an additional example where the records are in the columns instead of in the rows. Direct assignment works without errors in that case.

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),ncol=3)
m0 <- m

r <- c(10,20,30)

#For loop
print(
  system.time(
    for (k in 1:100000){  
      for (i in c(1,2))
        m[i,] <- r
    }))
print(m)

#     User      System verstrichen 
#     0.524       0.011       0.552 

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#     [1,]   10   20   30
#     [2,]   10   20   30
#     [3,]    3    6    9


#@docendo-discimus: Create new matrix
m <- m0
print(
  system.time(
  for (k in 1:100000){
    m[1:2, ] <- matrix(r, ncol = 3, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)})
)
print(m)

#     User      System verstrichen 
#     0.818       0.011       0.833 

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#     [1,]   10   20   30
#     [2,]   10   20   30
#     [3,]    3    6    9

#@docendo-discimus Transpose, modify columns, transpose again
m <- m0
print(
  system.time(
    for (k in 1:100000){
      m <- t(m)
      m[, 1:2] <- r
      m <- t(m)
      m}))

print(m)

#     User      System verstrichen 
#     1.870       0.010       1.895 

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#     [1,]   10   20   30
#     [2,]   10   20   30
#     [3,]    3    6    9

#Usage of different data structure with a transposed matrix
m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),nrow=3)
m0 <- m
print(m)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#     [1,]    1    4    7
#     [2,]    2    5    8
#     [3,]    3    6    9

print(
  system.time(
    for (k in 1:100000){
      m[,1:2] <- r
    }))

print(m)

#     User      System verstrichen 
#     0.241       0.013       0.255

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#     [1,]   10   10    7
#     [2,]   20   20    8
#     [3,]   30   30    9
```